# Lock command for discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I need to make a lock command for a bot I'm making with discord.js but I don't know how. I need it to lock the channel when I do ".lock" by changing "Send messages" setting for the "Community" role to false, and set it back to True when I do ".unlock".

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Listen to the command like any other command, and changing permissions on a role for a specific channel. https://discordjs.guide/

Comment: Can we see what you've tried so far? The DJS guide (linked above) provides all the information you will need. Use the tools and information available, then ask here when you have a solid attempt

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. Get the "community" role's id. Store it in some variable (I'm calling it `communityRoleId` in this example).
2. Call `<Message>.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(communityRoleId, { SEND_MESSAGES: false })` when someone calls the lock command. This creates a permission overwrite for the community role saying that that role can't send messages in the channel.
3. For the unlock command, you can either delete the permission overwrite you made with the lock command or edit it so the community role can send messages again. To delete it, you can just `<Message>.channel.permissionOverwrites.delete(communityRoleId)`, and to edit it, you can `<Message>.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(communityRoleId, { SEND_MESSAGES: true })`

Edit: Be sure to also run checks to see if the person using the command has an "admin" role or sufficient permissions or something like that, you don't want random people being able to lock channels!